# Flask-Uploads gives AttributeError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-3.5, flask-uploads

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST'] = '/home/kevin'
photos = UploadSet('photos', IMAGES)

configure_uploads(app, (photos,))
```

The above is my code, however it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 10, in <module>
    configure_uploads(app, (photos,))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flaskext/uploads.py", line 197, in configure_uploads
    should_serve = any(s.base_url is None for s in set_config.itervalues())
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'itervalues'
```

I'm using **Flask 0.10.1** and **Flask-Uploads 0.1.3**, which part of my code is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, Flask-Uploads 0.1.3 doesn't support Python 3 due to the call to `dict.itervalues()`.

I recently took over as maintainer of the Flask-Uploads project, and accepted a PR fixing the issue in [this commit](https://github.com/jeffwidman/flask-uploads/commit/231687b9084adde181b26923784a73008b38be8e).

The 0.2.0 release which includes this fix hasn't been pushed to Pypi yet, but until that happens you can install the Python 3 compatible version straight from GitHub:

```
pip install git+https://git@github.com/jeffwidman/flask-uploads.git
```

If you hit any issues, the issue tracker is here: https://github.com/jeffwidman/flask-uploads/issues

Comment: Cool and thanks! So that means Flask-Uploads 0.2.0 now support Python 3?

Comment: Yes, I haven't actually tagged the release because I just made a bunch of changes to modernize it and I'd like to have a few folks try it out and make sure nothing slipped through the cracks before I actually push it out to Pypi. All tests pass just fine, but I just started maintaining it, so not sure how reliable the test suite is. So try it out and file an issue if you run into anything.

Comment: Ah, just tried it and it works perfect! Thanks for the new version of Flask-Uploads :D

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Please push this to PyPi.

Answer (score 1):

`dict.itervalues()` is only in python2.x, I guess flask-uploads don't support 3.x yet and the `setup.py` also don't say that they support 3.x

Comment: Really? I installed it by `pip`, and there's no error or warning, also I didn't find it in the document...So that is unless I use python2 run the script, I'm not able to use flask-uploads right?

Comment: Install it successfully doesn't mean that we can use it. Sadly, python3.x don't support `dict.itervalues()`, you can try it youself, I'm afraid that you can't use it. Maybe you can file an issue there, wait the author to port it.