# Error While Importing from dnspython

Tags: python

I got the following error message while using dnspython.

```
>>> from dns import resolver
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dns/resolver.py", line 32, in <module>
import dns.flags
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dns/flags.py", line 51, in <module>
_by_value = dict([(y, x) for x, y in _by_text.iteritems()])
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Do anybody know how to fix it? I am using python 3.4. Alternatives to dnspython are also welcome answers.

Comment: Because it doesn't support Python 3? `dict.iteritems()` is a Python 2 function and removed in Python 3.

Comment: I installed it using pip for python 3

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't mean it support Python 3. Actually, I had asked a question like yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840765/flask-uploads-gives-attributeerror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libraries are not compatible with both python 2.7 and 3.x. Installing dnspython3 should do the trick as suggested in the [reported bug](https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython/issues/90)